# python, проблема с copy и deepcopy

Tags: python, dict, copy

имеется код:

```
my_dict = {'alpha': [1, 2, 3], 'beta': 0.3}

b = my_dict['alpha']
b.append(my_dict['beta'])

print(my_dict)
```

В выводе получаю:

```
{'alpha': [1, 2, 3, 0.3], 'beta': 0.3}
```

Неожиданно 0.3 появилось в словаре. Почему- мне не понятно, скорее всего трабл с копированием  во второй строке. Как исправить пока не понимаю.

Comment: В показанном вами коде нету ни copy, ни deepcopy. Как исправить — очевидно, использовать copy или deepcopy ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Предпочтительнее deepcopy, т.к. у Вас ключ 'alpha' в словаре my_dict - изменяемый объект. Если в дальнейшем будет меняться значение этого ключа - поверхностная копия не решит проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

все из за того, что вы не создаете копию, а ссылаетесь на уже существующий в памяти элемент, соответственно меняется оригинальный объект, вот вариант, где явно указывается создание копии:

```
my_dict = {'alpha': [1, 2, 3], 'beta': 0.3}

b = my_dict['alpha'].copy()
b.append(my_dict['beta'])

print(my_dict)
```